# Android SDK Version

Tags: android

I want to know about android version.
In other software, lower version is mostly compatible with higher version.
I dun get that android always ask higher SDK or ask same api version whenever I run the lower version of api or SDK.
It should able to cope with it, shouldn't it?
Another question is how do I download android SDK packages not from eclipse, coz it overwrite my existing SDK and I don't want to be like that.
Thanks alot.
I know that my quests are naive or I may be numb.
But dun neglect me.
Have a nice day ya'll.

Comment: You can target older API versions with each SDK, so it shouldn't be a problem to update your SDK.

Comment: Could you explain me with example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well there is certain reason for android always asking higher SDK or at least same SDK version since new features continues to evolve through generations of sdk. If your current project created using 2.2 SDK then there would be a chance that some code using in 2.2 doesn't work with 2.1. About the SDK packages, there is a way to download SDK packages not from eclipse, but I certainly not recommend you to do so.

Comment: why? Coz of our internet connection, I am afraid SDK update is not finished completely like always. Thus why I can't take risk to update online.

Comment: of course i can copy a sdk from somewhere else, but you need to make sure ur not gonna mess up your own sdk directories. Not safe in my idea really:)

Comment: I can update android SDK without overwriting the existing SDK, is that what you mean?

Comment: yups...just copy new sdk version into platforms folder, should work fine